# How to use jquery select get option value in C#?

Tags: c#, jquery

I use jquery get sample all value and text in C# ,but i don't know what to do.

[web sample]

```
<select name="s_townname2" id="group_select">
    <option value="111">A</option>
    <option value="222">B</option>
    <option value="333">C</option>
</select>
```

[C#]

```
string jquery = "$('select[name=\"s_townname2\"]')"
System.Web.UI.Page page = new System.Web.UI.Page();
ClientScriptManager cs = page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key", jquery, false);
```

Comment: you are right,but how can i use web and ajax?Can explain in detail?Thanks.

Comment: do you mean you need to get all the values available in the select, or just the selected item?

Comment: I want value and text pass in C# using Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
var text = $('#s_townname2').find(":selected").text();
var value = $('#s_townname2').find(":selected").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

did you mean you want text box value pass in c# using JQuery on click event ? If i am right then you need to use Web Method and ajax.